# Issues with Javascript Price Calculator - Price Not Showing

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm having issues with a simple price calculator I'm making.  I've learned Javascript and I went over everything and it looks fine, but I'm definitely missing something since the final price isn't appearing.  I've checked it a few times but maybe it needs a new set of eyes:

```
<form action="" name="costcalculator" id="costcalculator" onsubmit="return false;"> // I put name and ID to be safe

    <b>1.</b> What type of website do you need?<br>
    <input type="radio"  name="typesite" value="Standard" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    A standard website<br>
    <input type="radio"  name="typesite" value="Full Blog" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    A website that allows visitors to leave comments on blog posts<br>

<center><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" /></center><p>

<div id="totalPrice"></div> </form>
```

The script:

```
var typesite = new Array(); // typesite is taken from the HTML
 typesite["Standard"]=20;
 typesite["Full Blog"]=30;

function getLayoutPrice() // new name for function
{  
    var layoutPrice=0; // new name for the variable
    var theForm = document.forms["costcalculator"]; // comes from form name/ID
    var typeSite = theForm.elements["typesite"]; // new variable name and name from HTML
for(var i = 0; i < typeSite.length; i++)
{
    if(typeSite[i].checked)
    {
        layoutPrice = typesite[typeSite[i].value];
        break;
    }
}
return layoutPrice; // taken from the variable created earlier
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalPrice = getLayoutPrice();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price would be about $"+totalPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: `layoutPrice = typesite[typeSite[i].value];` I would change the name of one of these variables. It's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in current Chrome and Firefox and seems to work fine, as can be observed from running the snippet below.

```js
var typesite = new Array(); // typesite is taken from the HTML
 typesite["Standard"]=20;
 typesite["Full Blog"]=30;

function getLayoutPrice() // new name for function
{  
    var layoutPrice=0; // new name for the variable
    var theForm = document.forms["costcalculator"]; // comes from form name/ID
    var typeSite = theForm.elements["typesite"]; // new variable name and name from HTML
for(var i = 0; i < typeSite.length; i++)
{
    if(typeSite[i].checked)
    {
        layoutPrice = typesite[typeSite[i].value];
        break;
    }
}
return layoutPrice; // taken from the variable created earlier
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalPrice = getLayoutPrice();

    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price would be about $"+totalPrice;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="costcalculator" id="costcalculator" onsubmit="return false;"> // I put name and ID to be safe

    <b>1.</b> What type of website do you need?<br>
    <input type="radio"  name="typesite" value="Standard" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    A standard website<br>
    <input type="radio"  name="typesite" value="Full Blog" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    A website that allows visitors to leave comments on blog posts<br>

<center><input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" /></center><p>

<div id="totalPrice"></div> </form>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I looked at it again and apparently my script isn't being called, however the code does work if I put the form and the script on the same page.  I do have <script type="text/javascript" src="form-calculations.js"></script> in the head of the page but for the meantime I've put the script on the same page as the form.